# Label not updating in python tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, label

I'm writing a tkinter program, and I'm trying to update my label on the ui. However I can't get it to work. Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random, functools, string

root = Tk()

word_list = ["APPLE", "PEAR", "BANNANA"]

word = word_list [random.randint(0,2)]

hidden_word = ["_ "] * len(word)
print (word)


abc = ['_ '] * len(word)
guessed_letters = []

#Functions
def click_1 (key):
    if key in word:
        guessed_letters = ''.join([key])
        global abc
        abc = ''.join([key if key in guessed_letters else "_" for key in word])
    else:
        print ("Nope") ####TESTING#####


#Frames
hangman_frame = Frame(root)
hangman_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N)
letter_frame = Frame(root)
letter_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=S)

#Label
letters_label = Label(hangman_frame, textvariable=abc)
letters_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
```

(Just an excerpt, not all)

My question is that when ran, this section appears not to work:

```
letters_label = Label(hangman_frame, textvariable=abc)
```

where:

```
abc = ['_ '] * len(word)
    guessed_letters = []

#Functions
def click_1 (key):
    if key in word:
        guessed_letters = ''.join([key])
        global abc
        abc = ''.join([key if key in guessed_letters else "_" for key in word])
```

And nothing shows up, whereas when this is put:

```
letters_label = Label(hangman_frame, text=abc)
```

The label shows up, but does not update when the function click_1 is called.

Any reason to this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the `textvariable` option requires an instance of `StringVar` or `IntVar`.  You can't just pass it the name of a normal variable.

Generally speaking, you never need to use the `textvariable` option unless you specifically need the features of a `StringVar` or `IntVar` (such as having two widgets share the same data, or doing traces on the variable). I know lots of examples use it, but it just adds another object that you don't really need.

In order to update the text on a label, you would do this:

```
letters_label = Label(..., text="initial value")
...
def click_1(...):
    ...
    abc = ...
    letters_label.configure(text=abc)
```

Comment: That works _almost_ perfectly - it does not keep the changes, ie. when i press 'a', it changes to 'a', but when i press 'b', it only outputs 'b' and removes the 'a'. Any way to solve this?

Comment: can you please answer my question as it is frustrating me that it is doing this.

Comment: You must be replacing `a` with `b` instead of adding `b` to `a` when redefining `abc` before displaying it.